# Optimize MySQL code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Could someone please explain me how I could improve a query like this so it runs as fast as possible and it is also cleaner? As you can see I have 2 selects which are exactly the same, but I need to be able to the get the count out of this all, so I'm not sure what would be the best way to change something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users
WHERE users.activated = '1'
AND (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE()) FROM users AS users2 WHERE users2.id = users.id) >= '18' 
AND (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, CURDATE()) FROM users AS users2 WHERE users2.id = users.id) <= '28'
```

Basically I need to get the count of all users which are between 18 and 28 years old for example. `users.birthdate` is a date column.

Could someone please help? How would I be able to use the 2 `select`s from the `where` clause as just one so it doesn't execute the same thing 2 times?

EDIT:

Another example, I also have this query which I need to use multiple times in a where clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users
 WHERE ROUND((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * SIN(RADIANS(users.lat)) + COS(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * COS(RADIANS(users.lat)) * COS(RADIANS('$c_lng' - users.lng))))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.60934 * 1000) >= 1000
 AND ROUND((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * SIN(RADIANS(users.lat)) + COS(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * COS(RADIANS(users.lat)) * COS(RADIANS('$c_lng' - users.lng))))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.60934 * 1000) <= 5000
```

This one gets all the users which are between a distance of 1000 meters and 5000 meters from $c_lat and $c_lng that I pass.

Just trying to understand what's the best way to solve these kind of problems in MySQL.

Thanks!

Comment: Considering your comments to the first answer this question is way too broad for a good answer, but a rather generic one is: see `SQL correlated subquery in the SELECT clause example` at http://www.zentut.com/sql-tutorial/understanding-correlated-subquery/

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason why you would use a subquery for this.  A better way to write the query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM users u
WHERE u.activated = '1' AND
      u.birthdate <= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 18 years) AND
      u.birthdate >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 28 years);
```

As written, this query can take advantage of an index on `users(activated, birthdate)`.  In particular, the second condition might be better written as:  `u.birthdate > date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 29 years)`.

Note:  the exact logic for the date arithmetic might be a little off.  It is not clear exactly what you mean by "between 18 and 28".

Comment: iirc `between low and high` will work for date types.

Comment: Ok, my example was a little bad, that was just an example anyway, I have other subqueries that would repeat and execute the same thing 2 times, is there a way to avoid things like this so it doesn't execute the same thing 2 times? Like is there a way to get the age just one time and then use it in the where clause as many times as I want? Thanks!

Comment: @eXistenZ . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  If you have another question, please ask it as another question.  Sample data and desired results are very useful.

Comment: Updated my question above so you can see what I mean, my question is more general as to how to solve problems like these so I don't run the exact same code 2 times. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd example, you can try this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    ROUND((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * SIN(RADIANS(users.lat)) + COS(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * COS(RADIANS(users.lat)) * COS(RADIANS('$c_lng' - users.lng))))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.60934 * 1000) AS var_one,
    ROUND((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * SIN(RADIANS(users.lat)) + COS(RADIANS('$c_lat')) * COS(RADIANS(users.lat)) * COS(RADIANS('$c_lng' - users.lng))))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.60934 * 1000) AS var_two
FROM
    users
HAVING
    var_one >= 1000
    AND var_two <= 5000;
```

You usually use the calculation or comparison in the 'WHERE' clause area, try using 'HAVING' then set the filter based on the expected processed result of a column. Something like:

```
SELECT
    p.productID, 
    p.productName,
    COUNT(t.productID) AS transCount
FROM
    product p
    INNER JOIN transaction t ON t.productID = p.productID
HAVING
    transCount > 10;
```

This would display products with a transaction record greater than 10

Comment: Hmm, I tried something like this before but I ended up not using it because it seemed rather slow, as far as I know HAVING will run without any optimization at the end of the query so it tends to be slower, is there another way of doing this without using a HAVING clause? Thanks